# How to import data from notepad to sql server 2012 continuously

Tags: import, sql-server-2012

I have around 6 columns of data in notepad which can be updated on every seconds. I can import the data from notepad to sql server using import/export option but dont know how can I do it whenever a record is inserted in notepad.

Whenever a record inserted in notepad then it should also be inserted in sql server also. How can i achieve this. I m using sql server 2012.

Please help me out.

Comment: doesn't sound like an ideal scenario but you basically have 2 options for automation:  1) Use SSIS and write a ETL process or 2) write some code to watch this file, upon changes to the file, rename it and then consume it.

Comment: All I can say is you better have one beefy server that you plan on running this on or else it'll be about the only thing that it'll be doing.

Comment: @TMcKeown Can you please provide some link about SSIS and ETL process

Comment: it requires you have installed the SQL SERVER developer tools (visual studio etc), it is quite an extensive process, if you have any programming knowledge I would point you in that direction.  SSIS is very cumbersome and fragile and requires a lot of data typing knowledge as well as the difference between OLEDB and ADO connections etc...

Comment: but if you insist, here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137731.aspx

Comment: @TMcKeown I m having C# knowledge and using VS 2012 & SQL Server 2012. Thanks for your link. Will check it and let you know.